# Plain JavaScript / Ajax to get contents from multiple external files and append them to respective divs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am really bad at JavaScript hence need help. I am trying to assemble the final layout based on some conditions.

**My question :** I know the JavaScript is totally wrong. I am looking for the correct syntax and statement to get that content from multiple files and append them to respective divs.

**Please note:** I am not looking for any jQuery solutions as this is the only JavaScript Function in my template, and I don't want to load an entire Library for it.

My `index.php` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadLayout(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {document.getElementById("header").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
        {document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
        {document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
      }
var 
x=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.getElementsByTagName.clientWidth;
        if (x <= 800) {
            xmlhttp.open("GET","header1.php",true); // this should append to Div with ID "header"
        } else if (x > 800 && x <=1200) {
            xmlhttp.open("GET","body1.php",true); // this should append to Div with ID "body"
        } else if (x >1200) {
            xmlhttp.open("GET","footer1.php",true);// this should append to Div with ID "footer"
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    window.onload = loadLayout; // When the page first loads
    window.onresize = loadLayout; // When the browser changes size
    </script>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

My `header.php` file

```
if ($xyz == '20' && $xyz <= '60'){ 
    require_once 'some-1.php';
}
```

My `body.php` file

```
if ($xyz == '20' && $xyz <= '60'){ 
    require_once 'some-2.php';
}
```

My `footer.php` file

```
if ($xyz == '20' && $xyz <= '60'){ 
    require_once 'some-3.php';
}
```

Comment: Before I even attempt to write an answer for this (a proper answer is going to be an extensive one), may I ask why you want to load them into div elements and not simply use iframes for the same result?

Comment: how to use xmlhttprequest - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started - and - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: Well @icecub actually I just want to use a specific type of template part for a specific screen width. I want those parts to be called via Ajax while the other main layout is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below (fully commented) should help you:

```js
/* we put all your code inside an IIFE, so we don't pollute the global scope */
(function() {
  /* our AJAX helper function */
  function ajax(url, callback, method) {
    if (!method) method = 'GET';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
      callback.call(xhr, xhr.responseText);
    });
    xhr.send();
  }

  /* we create a variable to store our current layout
    (so, we only make the AJAX request if the layout has changed) */
  var lastLayout = [];

  function loadLayout() {
    /* we get the current width (didn't change your code) */
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName.clientWidth;
    /* and then, we use check what layout we must load */
    var layout = width <= 800 ? ['body'] : width <= 1200 ? ['header', 'body'] : ['header', 'body', 'footer'];

    /* if the new layout is different from the last loaded */
    if (lastLayout.toString() !== layout.toString()) {
      /* firstly, we set our current loaded to the new one */
      lastLayout = layout;

      /* we empty all the divs */
      document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = '';

      /* loop through the layout divs that should be loaded */
      layout.forEach(function(str) {
        /* we use the variable to dinamically open the correct PHP file */
        ajax(str + '1.php', function(result) {
          /* and then, we use the variable again to fill the correct div */
          document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = result;
        });
      });
    }
  }  

  window.onload = window.onresize = loadLayout;
})();
```

Comment: While this one more or less works close to what I was looking for, Could you suggest a way to remove the added content upon browser resize? Because once the content appears, it stays there even upon browser re-sizing to old size.

Comment: @VikramRao that's exactly what I said in my note. If you want to empty the divs, you must get one by one and do `.innerHTML = ''´. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Buzinzs Now I face another problem. Earlier those three parts were visible together upon browser resize but now any one part is visible. Either the Header or the Body or the footer.

Comment: @VikramRao but did you keep the line: `document.getElementById(layout).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;`?

Comment: @Buzinzs Yes I did. I actually just copy pasted your entire code to test.

Comment: @VikramRao so, please, show us your webpage URL, so I can take a look what's happening

Comment: @Buzinzs Here you go.... http://vikramrao.com/test3/index2.php also index.php is the first version of your answer.

Comment: @VikramRao what's wrong with that `index2.php` version? It seems that it's working great for me...

Comment: @Buzinzs Okay let me explain in detail... Lets say the base layout stays with a body and if the screen width is above <=799px I want to add the Header.php div to it and further if the width is >=800px && <=1200 px then I want to add the Footer.php. So upon resizing, the basic body must stay intact and based on the width the other two elements keep appearing and vanishing. With index2.php, at any given point of time any one thing appears, either the Header or the Body or the Footer.

Comment: So, if screen <= 800, then header + body, if > 800 and <= 1200, body + footer, and if > 1200, only body, that's it?

Comment: If screen <= 800, Only Body, if > 800 and <= 1200, Body + Header, and if > 1200, Header + Body + Footer?

Comment: @VikramRao instead of getting all the content from AJAX and then emptying them on resize, and then getting them again, couldn't you only hide/show the divs when resizing?

Comment: That's the idea. Actuall, my mail layout consists of a Header, Body and Footer. Now I want that if the screen-width is very large like >=1400 or so then I want to add another Sidebar on the right side and also move the top Navigation dropdown to a left side sidebar with Vertical navigation. Similarly if the size is between 100-1400 then I just want the top-nav to move left in Vertical fashion. less than 800 I want just the normal original layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help